# How to detect if process is detached from Linux terminal in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

I have a compiled C++ program running on Linux Ubuntu. Every second this program clears terminal and prints some new measurement data.
However in some cases I want to run this program with '&' to continue working in current terminal.
Is there a way to detect in C++ if program is running in detached mode and stop clearing and printing?

I was thinking if maybe I could catch '&' as an argument, but my program has varying number of arguments that could possibly grow in the future so that doesnt seem to be an elegant solution.

Comment: The shell run-in-background with `&` doesn't "detach" the program from the terminal. The program still is connected to the terminal, otherwise output wouldn't work. I don't know how input is handled though. You could use [`isatty(STDIN_FILENO)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) to check its status perhaps?

Comment: You can not cat & as an input, but you could additional redirect output to somewhere with >>. So you do not ser the output anymore.

Comment: If you truly want to detach a command from the terminal, run it not only in the background, but also using the [`nohup`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nohup.1.html) command, and redirect both input and output from and to `/dev/null`.